# Mechanical Turk in Firefox - setInterval and setTimeout not working

Tags: javascript, firefox, mechanicalturk

I am trying to run an external web page in Mechanical Turk. It uses setTimeout and setInterval.

If I invoke the external web page directly in Firefox or Chrome, it all works.
If I invoke the external web page in MTurk in Chrome, it all works.
If I invoke the external web page in MTurk in Firefox, setTimeout and setInterval fail to work.

Any suggestions for fixes or work-arounds would be gratefully received.

Comment: What do you mean 'fail to work'? Please provide error log.

Comment: @Sanandrea, there is no error message. A Javascript function is set to be executed after a specified delay. In the combination of Mechanical Turk in Firefox, it simply does not execute. (Whereas in Firefox without Turk, the function is executed; ditto in Chrome with or without Turk.) Here is the first segment of code, which simply updates an onscreen clock:

Comment: function trialClock()
{  var minutesLeft = Math.floor(timeLeft / 60);
   var secondsLeft = timeLeft - minutesLeft*60;
   document.getElementById("timeReport").innerHTML = minutesLeft + " m "+ secondsLeft + " s";
   timeLeft--;
   if (timeLeft > 0)
   {  clockTimer = setTimeout(trialClock,1000);}
   else
   {  timedOut(); }
}  (Sorry about linefeeds - newby on Stackoverflow.)